# macOS Big Sur NSImage setFlipped Randomly Flipping

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsimage

In macOS Objective-C I was using a (depreciated) setFlipped to flip an NSimage in a custom ToolTip Window. The way this code has always worked is [TipImage setFlipped:NO] makes the images in the correct orientation. This has always worked fine, but in Big Sur some of the images are randomly flipping to the incorrect orientation. Maybe a Big Sur bug, but setFlipped is also depreciated so that could be an issue also. If I change to [TipImage setFlipped:YES] then all images are correctly flipped (and no random change in orientation like if I use NO). If I remove the //[TipImage setFlipped] code entirely, then all images are flipped with also no random changes in orientation. So, I guess my question is: Can I remove the //[TipImage setFlipped] code entirely (causing images to draw flipped), but somehow add alternative code to flip them? New to macOS Obj-C so any help would be appreciated.

```
@interface CustomToolTip : NSObject {   
    NSImageView             *imgView;
}

NSRect        contentRect       = { { 100, 100 }, { 0, 20 } };
NSRect        imageFrame        = { { -120, 10 }, { 0, 0 } };

imgView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
[imgView setEditable:NO];
[imgView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
[[window contentView] addSubview:imgView ];

NSSize        sizeImage               = [TipImage size];
sizeImage.width = [ [ TipImage bestRepresentationForRect:NSZeroRect context:nil hints:nil] pixelsWide];
sizeImage.height = [ [ TipImage bestRepresentationForRect:NSZeroRect context:nil hints:nil] pixelsHigh];
[ TipImage setSize:sizeImage];

[TipImage setFlipped:NO];
[imgView setImage:TipImage];
[imgView setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(-winSize.width/2 + sizeImage.width/2,winSize.height/2 -sizeImage.height/2 +10)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the setFlipped:NO from the original thumbnail and then usinmg respectFlipped:YES seems to have fixed it.

```
//[m_imageThumb[index] setFlipped:NO];
[m_imageThumb[index] drawInRect:rtImage fromRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, [m_imageThumb[index] size].width, [m_imageThumb[index] size].height) operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0 respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
```